# How to check which rendition is actually getting played in hls playback using videojs/video-contrib-hls?

Tags: video-streaming, video.js, http-live-streaming

I am using videojs and video-contrib-hls for HLS playback. I am trying to figure out which particular segment is being played for a time range. For example say, if segment duration is 6 seconds then i want to know for 0-6 second which rendition(288/576/720 px etc.) is being played, for 6-12 seconds which rendition is being played. In video-contrib-hls , we are buffering data in advance, so if the video is playing at 3 second it might be possible that we have already buffered the data of 6-12 second, but in case of mediachange(SWITCHING MEDIA) we again append another segment of 6-12 second in buffer. So i am not able to figure out in actual which segment is being played between 6-12 second. How can i get this info?